# App that reads and writes to Facebook

Tags: android, ios, facebook, html, blogs

I want to create an app that allows a user to post to Facebook, but I want this to view posts by other users using the app, so basically a blog app in between friends using the app. How do i go about doing this, what API's do i use?

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Checkout,how [**`Oauth2`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/) Works and check the [**`Facebook Sdk`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/) for android and ios,there is a sample application in the sdk package,try that it will help and make you know how to use it in your application.